# Using the file command to count script files

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I need to use the `file` command to count the number of scripts a directory.

I know how to get the file type using `file`:

```
file test
test: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

But how would I use `file` to count the number of script files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Script files are usually executable, you can find all executable files in a directory easily by using `find`. Note that these commands for finding executable files will find **all** executable files, not only scripts).

```
find . -type f -executable
```

This will find all exectutable files in the directory you run it from. It will include files from sub-directories as well, to ignore sub-directories, add `-maxdepth 1` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
```

Now, this will give a list of all files, not a count of them. To recive a count, pipe the result to `wc -l`:

```
find . -type f -executable | wc -l
```

---

In the case where some of the files are script files, but not executable, the following commands can be used:

- If only files in current directory should be counted:

  `file -b * | grep " script" | wc -l`
- If files in sub-directories should be included:

  `find . -type f -exec file -b {} \; | grep " script" | wc -l`

A space is added before "script" in the grep command to avoid invalid matches (such as "descriptive" in TIF files).

Comment: but this will only count scripts that has execute bit set. If the OP wants to include real scripts that don't have execute bit then you need to use `file`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That is correct. I added one more command to the answer that will work in the case such files exists.

Comment: No need for  `find` in the last method, `file * | grep script | wc -l` works just as well.

Comment: @xenoid Good catch, however, it doesn't seem to work recursively. Added it to the answer.

Comment: This will also find programs that are not scripts ...

Comment: If TIF files are in the directory being searched the `grep` needs to be modified when `file` is used. Running `file` on TIF images produces output with "description" (at least on my system). Try `file * | grep " script" | wc -l`.

Comment: @GreenMatt Good point. Changed the answer to reflect this.